# Tensorflow seq2seq `feed_previous' argument`

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation

I'm using the built-in `tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq()` function and I have some problems with the `feed_previous` argument, during training, the groundtruth is fed into the decoder while during testing we feed the output of the last time step to the decoder. The problem is that once I set the `feed_previous` argument I can't change that argument. I want to test my model every epoch, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4433079e7f317724eaa92ec120c6b1c3c0c52f2f/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L822), you can provide a boolean tensor for feed_previous.

```
feed_previous = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
model = tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq(..feed_previous=feed_previous...)
sess.run(loss, feed_dict={feed_previous=is_training, ...})
```